# Regex/ PHP - Finding an String inside a text with two variables inside

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm looking to find all matches of an Url inside a log file, then extract some data of those matches. I'm not good at all with regular expression so i'm not being able to find.

Ocurrances i'm trying to find:

```
// this is the string i want to find,
// in every match 1113321569 and the acceses_token will change

Api::log : {"url":"https://api.test.com//v0/notes/1113321569/notes?access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJydGUiOiIxNTYyMDM5NjUxNDgxIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MTAzMTU1MzI0MywidXNlcl9"
```

Basically i need a regular expression to find that text having `1113321569` and `eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJydGUiOiIxNTYyMDM5NjUxNDgxIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MTAzMTU1MzI0MywidXNlcl9` as a variable, and after i found the whole string i need to extract those two variables.

Could you guys help me?

Comment: Is that a json string you have cut off?

Comment: It's inside a log file witch contains some json,the full line would look something like this  `[2019-06-04 19:24:23] INFO: Api::log : {"url":"https://api.test.com//v0/notes/1113321569/notes?access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJydGUiOiIxNTYyMDM5NjUxNDgxIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MTAzMTU1MzI0MywidXNlcl9"
,"fields":{"answers":[],"origenId":302},"response":{"code":"invalid_request","message":" .","token":"269b9385-b189-46df-9742-6875457b7368","http_code":400}} [] `

Comment: But isn't token the same in the URL as the variable?

Comment: Not actually they are different token, one is an access token and the other is from the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this expression might work:

```
"url":"(.+\/([0-9]{10})\/.+access_token=(.+?))"
```

and our desired outputs are in groups [1], [2] and [3].

#### TEST

```
$re = '/"url":"(.+\/([0-9]{10})\/.+access_token=(.+?))"/s';
$str = 'Api::log : {"url":"https://api.test.com//v0/notes/1113321569/notes?access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJydGUiOiIxNTYyMDM5NjUxNDgxIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MTAzMTU1MzI0MywidXNlcl9"
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dgykkl/1/)

#### OUTPUT

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(157) ""url":"https://api.test.com//v0/notes/1113321569/notes?access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJydGUiOiIxNTYyMDM5NjUxNDgxIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MTAzMTU1MzI0MywidXNlcl9""
    [1]=>
    string(149) "https://api.test.com//v0/notes/1113321569/notes?access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJydGUiOiIxNTYyMDM5NjUxNDgxIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MTAzMTU1MzI0MywidXNlcl9"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "1113321569"
    [3]=>
    string(88) "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJydGUiOiIxNTYyMDM5NjUxNDgxIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MTAzMTU1MzI0MywidXNlcl9"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great for the second thing i have to do witch is finding the values of `1113321569 ` and `eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJydGUiOiIxNTYyMDM5NjUxNDgxIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MTAzMTU1MzI0MywidXNlcl9` but what i'm actually trying to find first is the whole $str that you defined inside a file (all the appearances of the url)

Comment: *$1, $2 and $3.* you mean *[1], [2] and [3].*? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like the regex `(?<=\/)(\d+)(?=\/).+(?:=)(\S+)(?:")`:

```
preg_match('/(?<=\/)(\d+)(?=\/).+(?:=)(\S+)(?:")/', $input_line, $output_array);
```

[image: Visualised]

This makes use of both positive look-behinds and positive look-aheads to group the two targets:

```
array(3
    0   =>  1113321569/notes?access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJydGUiOiIxNTYyMDM5NjUxNDgxIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MTAzMTU1MzI0MywidXNlcl9"
    1   =>  1113321569
    2   =>  eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJydGUiOiIxNTYyMDM5NjUxNDgxIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MTAzMTU1MzI0MywidXNlcl9
)
```

This can be seen working on Regex101 **[here](https://regex101.com/r/TCTigL/1/)** and PHPLiveRegex **[here](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/sxX)**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's actually very close of what i'm trying to achieve. What should i add in order to include the whole text in the first position of the array 
 because it's currently  returning everything after the first variable match.